# Android limiting editext length including decimal places

Tags: android, android-edittext, maxlength

I would like to know is there any method is there for  limiting the decimal places of edittext by xml method.. I know there is method for limiting programmatically..

```
android:maxLength="6"
```

Comment: You can implement this using textwatcher

Answer (score 0):

android:inputType="numberDecimal"

Comment: not that...I would like to give like maximum six numbers for example if 1245.34 ..ok... 4 maximum numbers and 2 decimals... and dont want allow a number without decimal to six numbers.. for example 239876 not allowed..

Comment: i think you can do only by the code there no attribute for the set the decimal place vai the xml

Answer (score 0):

This is possible through coding...
Use `text watcher` and apply the code in `onTextChanged` which will check the number of digits after the decimal values.